# What is a word that describes the area between centre and edge?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am looking for a proper word that define a location or an area between centre point and edge point of a plain/ place.

`Centre of the forest` ............ `(What?) of the forest` .............. `Perimeter/ edge of the forest`.

I had come to a dictionary but still I can not get the definition.
(https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/the-outer-parts-of-objects-or-spaces)

Would you suggest some words for that?

Comment: Probably a job for a thesaurus, starting with something like "inside". Words will vary depending on the object being described. For example, for a forest you might use "interior", in water "depths", in a building "bowels", etc. There are also some technical words for different parts of a wheel.

Answer (score 2):

*Interior* could be an option, though it draws a distinction from perimeter more than it does from center (i.e., the center is located in the interior).

See noun definitions 8 and 11 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interior

Comment: In the same way, “surrounding area” distinguishes the area from the center and not the perimeter. Strange there isn’t a common word that does both (well, that I can think of!)

Answer (score 1):

That part of the forest is called "the forest".

The  "center" is often called "**[the heart](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heart%20of%20the%20forest%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**".